# How to display promotion price when qty is 0 in magento

Tags: php, magento, product

I am building an online shop where I want to display on the category page and also on the product page the special price also when the qty is 0 and stock is manageable. The idea is to say that the product can be on demand in 24-48 hours and it has a discount but the product is not in actual stock of the client but it can arrive to the customer in 24-48 hours.

How can I make this in Magento because when I look now is taking only the original price and not the promotional price when qty is 0.

Answer (score 0):

in magento version 1.9.1.0 it displays product with special price if it is out of stock so no need to change in code in magento. if not display there then use

```
 echo $_product->getFinalPrice();
```

for display promotional price.

Comment: I am using 1.8.1 version. Also the price that is take in the price.phtml is Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price as the promotion price.

Comment: have you added special price in admin panel product edit ->price -> special price ? also check have you set from date and to date for special price ?

Comment: I am adding a price in the normal price section and the sync software that is adding the price and qty in the shop every day is adding the price in "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price". By default is seems that Magento 1.8.1 if it finds a price in "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price" then this is taking as a special price but only when qty is bigger than 0

Comment: if you will use this <?php echo $_product->getMsrp();?>  then you will get special price even if product is out of stock. if not worked then you need to set special prices in special price field in magento backend.

Comment: With this I only make the display but when I add to shopping cart is not working because is taking the actual price. I want to have posibility to add and order it even if is out of stock because it will take longer to arrive to the client but it will arrive.

Answer (score 0):

From what it appears you simply want to discount active in stock products and stop doing so when they're out of stock and then notify the customers that they have a lead time of 24-48 hours if so.

There's a Magento inventory option to do just that:

admin/system_config/edit/section/cataloginventory

Then you need to add a promo that discounts products that are quantity > 0
The promo would reduce necessary products to the 'regular price' but not if their inventory is 0.

admin/promo_quote/new

By default Magento does not give you those promotions so you'd have to use a third party module for such detection/discount such as Amasty which has some of the most robust, stable, compatibly modules in the business:

https://amasty.com/

Comment: This is not really want I want to do. I have to have the possibility to order a product that is not in stock(qty=0) and also have a promotion on this product. I can display the promotion but when I add the product in the shopping cart the price is not good anymore because is taking the normal price and not the "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price"